# autocomplete with Materialize - text instead of optional image

Tags: autocomplete, materialize

I am using Materialize Autocomplete and I wonder if there is a way to use text instead of "optional image". Why? In case the text is not unique then the user will not know which one to choose. It might happen that the options will be names and there might two people with the same name and surname.

When typing my question I found out that I cannot use duplicate entries in data

```
    data: {
        "Radek": myself,
        "Radek": some other Radek,
        "Radoslav": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
    },
```

[js fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/8e7kvf6r/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the [source](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v0.98.0/dist/js/materialize.js) you find the following lines relevant for the images:

```
autocompleteOption.append('<img src="'+ data[key] +'" class="right circle"><span>'+ key +'</span>');
```

and

```
var img = $el.find('img');
$el.html("<span>" + beforeMatch + "<span class='highlight'>" + matchText + "</span>" + afterMatch + "</span>");
$el.prepend(img);
```

This prevents us from using the `image-attribute` for anything other than images.

We can insert something like this to trick Materialize

```
"Radoslav": " style="display: none;">Inserted Text <br><span style="display: none`
```

but it will just be converted to text resulting in a option equivalent to

```
"Inserted Text Radoslav": none
```

So there is sadly nothing to be gained here.

If you are looking to insert a `linebreak`, however, you can use this answer on [How to force Materialize autocomplete text to flow to new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544098/8106583)

Comment: this question was the first one. Then I thought I might place the "additional" text on a new line. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I just added the link if someone else comes by with the same problem. Happy to help!