# How to force Materialize autocomplete text to flow to new line?

Tags: javascript, css, autocomplete, materialize

I need duplicates in the suggested autocomplete. Why?
 There might two people with the same name and surname. I am using Materialize and it does not offer that feature. I was thinking to add some extra text for example email or so to make it work the way I need. To make it look nicer I want the "extra" text be always on new line.

But I do not know how to do that. I tried `<BR>`, `&#10;` and `\n` but it did not work. Any idea how to make it work?

```
    data: {
        "Radek Surname - radeksurname@ymail.com": null,
        "Radek<BR> new line": null,
        "Radoslav": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/radek/8e7kvf6r/17/

[image]

it looks like the BR tag was removed and is not in HTML source code anymore. See the picture.

Comment: Try `\n` and use [`white-space: pre-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) in the CSS

Comment: not sure how I can use CSS. I tried `\n`, did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Materialize `0.98.0` does a sort of doubled `html-conversion` because of the highlighting. [See Source](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v0.98.0/dist/js/materialize.js)

Every option is first converted to a `DOM-object`. Then via `.text()` the text is extracted again. This is what killed the `<br>` solution. But this is then again converted to `DOM-object`.

So we can cleverly do a double escape like so:

```
data: {
    "Radek Surname &lt;br&gt; radeksurname@ymail.com": null,
    "Radek &lt;br&gt; new line": null,
    "Radoslav": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
},
```

Because `&lt;br&gt;` converts to `<br>` which converts to a line break.

No aditional `js` or `css` needed.

```js
function sendItem(val) {
    document.getElementById('log').textContent = val + '\n' +
          document.getElementById('log').textContent;
}

$(function () {
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
            "Radek Surname&lt;br&gt; radeksurname@ymail.com": null,
            "Radek&lt;br&gt; new line": null,
            "Radoslav": 'http://placehold.it/250x250'
        },
        onAutocomplete: function(txt) {
          sendItem(txt);
          alert(txt);
        },
        limit: 20, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete" autocomplete="off">
                <label for="autocomplete-input">Type my name - Radek</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also: JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sjtznqh5/

Comment: works perfectly. Could you please explain the double escaping part? I thought that `&lt;` escapes `<` onece

Comment: Yes, `&lt;` escapes `<` just onec. I just called double-escaped, because we need to go an extra step. Firstly `&lt;br&gt;` escapes `<br>`. Secondly `<br>` escapes a linebreak. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: I think I got it now ... ;-)  Although it might no be needed because you solved this one... Does this question have a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65520784/autocomplete-with-materialize-text-instead-of-optional-image

Answer (score 4):

extremely inelegant, but quick and dirty:

add to css:

```css
.autocomplete-content span
{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

and in js:

```
{
  "Radek\n new line": null,
  [`Or Radek
another new line`]: null
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c6revjmu/2/

Comment: Doesn't seem particularly inelegant to me, but rather the only way to still use that particular `autocomplete` plugin with its limited options.

Comment: I like your solution ... it is elegant. Just in case Materialize something changes it might not work. The other solution will work, I guess.